# .NET Billboard Control

Tags: .net, ajax, controls

I still can't seem to get this to work.  If anyone else has any ideas I would really appreciate it.  The two websites whose controls I am trying to duplicate is mtv.com and nba.com.  I couldn't get jCarousel or the adrotator to have four images that rotate.  One large image and three small images.  If anyone has any ideas please let me know.

Hello,

Does anyone know where I can find a billboard control?  I'm not sure what it's really called but I'm going to call it a billboard control.  Examples of these are at the three below websites.  Basically what I'm talking about is anywhere from 3 to 5 images or html files that rotate every couple of seconds with a preview of these images/html files to the side or below.  I am looking for something I can use with C# .net.  Any help would be much appreciated.

espn.go.com
mtv.com
nba.com

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET WebForms comes with that control. It is called [`AdRotator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.adrotator.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the [.NET AdRotator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.adrotator.aspx) control ? That supports the most basic use cases, and it shouldn't be too much hassle to extend it and add functionality if needed. It is the closest to what you need, that is built into the framework.

Another solution would be to use the [jCarousel with jQuery](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/). Depending on your specific needs, it could be a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

**[This might help...uses AdRotator](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=202)**